# Where is += method located for int in scala

Tags: scala, types, primitive-types

Is +=(or any assignment operators) a method in scala for Int type.

For example,

```
var x=5
x+=1
```

Here I am able to use += method only when it is a variable.

I am not able to do,

```
5+=1
```

Does scala compiler considers this method as a special case?

Why it is not available in scala.Int class?

Comment: What do you expect `5+=1` to actually do? I don't know Scala, but I don't see any reason for it to allow you to overwrite a primitive's value...

Comment: I thought there is no operator in scala(only methods), so there will not be a difference between value and variable.

Comment: 5.+(1) and x.+(1) will work consistently, so I expect this operator to behave in the same way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `+=` method, it is expanded to `x = x + 1` by the compiler. This is detailed in the [specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators):

**6.12.4 Assignment Operators**

> Let's consider an assignment operator such as += in an infix operation
>   l += r, where l, r
>
> are expressions. This operation can be re-interpreted as an operation
>   which corresponds to the assignment
>
> ```
> l = l + r
> ```
>
> except that the operation's left-hand-side l is evaluated only once.
>
> The re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are
>   fulfilled.
>
> 1. The left-hand-side l does not have a member named +=, and also cannot be converted by an implicit conversion to a value with a member
>      named +=.
> 2. The assignment l = l + r is type-correct. In particular this implies that l refers to a variable or object that can be assigned to,
>      and that is convertible to a value with a member named +.

Comment: So you could do this for any method that fulfills the condition? E.g. 
`obj1 concat= obj2`?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz - I don't think so, this only applies to operators which are lexically non-empty sequences of operator characters. The [lexical syntax](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html) section defines operator chars as printable ascii characters which are not whitespace, letters, digits, parenthesis or delimiters.